# Problem with DEVMODE.dmCopies field

Tags: c++, windows, printing, gdi

I'm writing a printing application and i having trouble with dmCopies field of DEVMODE structure. This field specifies number of document copies printed. When i print multipage document (two pages and more) - setting up dmCopies works fine, but when one-page document printed dmFields ignored. First i think that problem in my application, but in standard microsoft example (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsPrintSample) it present too. What ways for workaround of that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably specific to your printer (assuming Microsoft code is not buggy (no ?))
Maybe this page can help you:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197393
The end of the report speaks about some workarounds to dmcopies.